# How to import multiple terraform resource instances?

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-github

I am trying to import already existing resources, these cannot be recreated, and there are many.

There is configuration that is basic to all resources and for some there are small changes.

I would like to import all the resources with a single command, doing it one by one is tedious and prone to mistakes.
Currently importing single resources with:

```
terraform import 'github_repository.repo_config["repo2"]' repo2
```

What would the `import` command look like if it were to import all of the resources?

The configuration is as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "github" {
  owner = "medecau"
}

variable "repo_config" {
  type = map(object({
    description  = string
    homepage_url = string
    topics       = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "repo1" = {
      description  = "Repo 1"
      homepage_url = "https://medecau.github.io/repo1/"
      topics       = ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3"]
    }
    "repo2" = {
      description  = "Repo 2"
      homepage_url = null
      topics       = null
    }
  }
}
variable "default_repo_config" {
  type = object({
    description  = string
    homepage_url = string
    topics       = list(string)
  })
  default = {
    description  = ""
    homepage_url = ""
    topics       = []
  }
}

data "github_repositories" "medecau_repos" {
  query           = "user:medecau"
  include_repo_id = true
}

resource "github_repository" "repo_config" {
  # cast to set to remove duplicates
  for_each = toset(data.github_repositories.medecau_repos.names)
  name     = each.value

  description  = lookup(var.repo_config, each.value, var.default_repo_config).description
  homepage_url = lookup(var.repo_config, each.value, var.default_repo_config).homepage_url
  topics       = lookup(var.repo_config, each.value, var.default_repo_config).topics

  has_issues           = true
  has_projects         = false
  has_wiki             = false
  vulnerability_alerts = true
  security_and_analysis {
    advanced_security {
      status = "enabled"
    }
    secret_scanning {
      status = "enabled"
    }
    secret_scanning_push_protection {
      status = "enabled"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is still not possible, and I believe there is nothing on the roadmap for it.

Answer (score 2):

In Terraform v1.5.0 and later, you can use import block to import many resources at once: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import

Comment: This even adds the benefit of making it reviewable before applying as well as to run it within CI/CD. Awesome to learn Terraform finally supports this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a shell script to automate the importing process. The idea is to declare an array of the ID of the resources that are going to be imported, then loop through the array and input the variables to the command.

Here is the example that I used to import multiple IAM roles to my tfstate.

```
# Declare a list of roles that will be imported
roles=("role-1" "role-2" "role-3")
# Loop through the array and import the roles to tfstate
for role in "${roles[@]}"; do
    terraform import -var="customer_region=${customer_region}" "aws_iam_role.roles[""\"${role}\"""]" "$role"
done
```

Hopefully this idea can help to automate the importing process. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Importing multiple resources with single `terraform import ..` call is not supported natively as of now by terraform.

However [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) could be something which can reduce your effort. Please go through the [Terraformer Github documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/docs/github.md) to verify if this works for you.

**Note:** Supports only organizational resources.

Comment: Appreciate the help here but I really need it for personal use.